Как уменьшить элемент, чтобы он помещался в размеры мобильного экрана
Я верстаю сайт, у меня на нем есть карусель (owl-carousel) с фото (ширина основного изображения 500px).
Мне нужно чтобы эта карусель помещалась на телефонах (где ширина окна может быть меньше 500px). При задании контейнера с шириной меньше 500px, часть контента просто обрезается.
Каким образом можно уменьшить весь элемент не пытаясь уменьшать по отдельности все его части (так как это сделать трудно)? Возможно есть какое-то простое решение, но я верстаю впервые, поэтому видимо не вижу решения.

Карусель которую нужно уменьшить



Что происходит когда элемент не вмещается



Что происходит когда уменьшается ширина контейнера-родителя



А вы уверены, что owl-carousel отрабатывает событие resize? Возможно стоит уменьшить экран, перезагрузить страницу и owl-carousel сама подстроится под доступные размеры.

Нет, она точно сама не подстраивается под нужные размеры

Можно использовать величину блока в vw (процент относительно ширины экрана. 100vw - 100% ширины экрана). Или можно иcпользовать @media, чтобы изменять свойства элементов при определенной ширине экрана
